# flutter getting the row data of sounding recorder in real-time

Tags: flutter

when users start recording their sound, I want to show the audio wave in real-time. I have tried FFmpeg to cover the audio file into PCM. But it was slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[noise_meter](https://pub.dev/packages/noise_meter) package from flutter may help you here.
You will have to convert the reading into a meaningful structure and then plot your wave.

Comment: but here is an error when I use this package: does not specify a Swift version and none of the targets (`Runner`) integrating.